# How can I customize a suffix snippet, replacing the variable in VS Code?

Tags: java, typescript, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I'm developing my Java project with VS Code when I find some powerful snippets:

[suffix code snippets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoq8b.png)

After I type a variable name and type `.sysout`, `.cast` and so on, the snippet suggestion pop out. When inserting, it leads to:

res.sysout => `System.out.println(res);`

res.cast => `(()(res))`

...

I'm curious about how to realize this feature in my VS Code. By the time, I didn't find anything useful at [redhat-developer/vscode-java](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java).

Then I want to transplant the snippet to support JS/TS, and other languages.

I detailedly read [VS Code's doc about snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets), find something that might be useful:

> The following variables can be used:
>
> - `TM_SELECTED_TEXT` The currently selected text or the empty string
> - `TM_CURRENT_LINE` The contents of the current line
> - ...

However, when I try to create the snippet, I don't know how to replace the variable name. In other words, I can get the variable name by `TM_CURRENT_LINE`, insert a snippet, but the previous variable name remains. For instance,

res.log => `resconsole.log(res);`

Comment: look at Hyper Snippets extension, where you can add code to the snippet and capture the variable as part of the snippet prefix

Comment: Correction **HyperSnips**

Comment: @rioV8 Yeah I've tried this extension. Could you please show some examples? I'm a little confused when using it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is called post-fix completion: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-editing#_postfix-snippet-shortcuts

For TS/JS, there are some extensions support that, for example:

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ipatalas.vscode-postfix-ts

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, this extension is what I need :)