# How can I create VS Code snippets that consume pre-existing text placed before the snippet prefix and use it in the snippet body?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I want to make snippet for console.log(variable) but instead to have prefix I want to make this with "suffix". Here's an example:

```
var name = "Marco";
var car = "Volvo";

name.log > TAB > console.log(name);
```

When I write my variable "name" after that ".log" like in example above. After that pressing TAB key on keyboard i want to get my "console.log(name);".
When I do it like this: car.log > TAB, I want to get "console.log(car);".

Comment: What would you want to happen if the object you're operating on in this type of context actually has an attribute or method literally named `log`?

Comment: Counter-proposal: you don't actually want this. What you want is a way to log a given thing, e.g., by wrapping a given "chunk" of code with `console.log(CHUNK)` *(also more versatile, IMO)*.

Comment: @esqew log.log > TAB > console.log(log);

Comment: @DaveNewton
Yes that is it, but how to achive that without snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of other options, notably see [How can I customize a suffix snippet, replacing the variable in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76088351/836330) and the extension mentioned there:

[TS/JS postfix completion](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ipatalas.vscode-postfix-ts) built-in support for `someVar.log` => `console.log(someVar)`

You can also automate the process that of replacing the existing text with a snippet, **BUT** then you must use a keybinding trigger and not a snippet prefix.  No extension is necessary though.  In your `keybindings.json`:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+c",            // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      "cursorHomeSelect",
      {
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "args": {
          "snippet": "console.log(${TM_SELECTED_TEXT})",
        }
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

For this second version you just type `name` and then <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

Comment: This is better than my case. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the documentation for Snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets), I don't think what you're asking for is supported.

The mechanism for using snippets is based on exact matches of text (the `prefix` field), and while [the variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables) include things like `TM_CURRENT_LINE` and `TM_CURRENT_WORD`, and even given those, I can't see a way to work them to do what you want.

The closest I could get was

```json
"test": {
    "prefix": ".log",
    "body": "console.log(${TM_CURRENT_LINE/^(\\s+.*?)?(\\w+)\\.log(.*)$/$2/})"
}
```

But I don't know how to "consume" / remove the pre-existing text preceding the snippet prefix.

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is

- type `name`
- select `name`, use`Ctrl+D`
- type `clog`

`clog` is the following snippet:

```json
"consolelog": {
    "prefix": "clog",
    "body": "console.log(${TM_SELECTED_TEXT})"
}
```